# Specify 2 actions at once using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have a button where I want to use JavaScript to both change the text and change the color of the text.  I know I can do it with the code I have pasted below.  To me that seems redundant.  Is there a better / shorter way to accomplish this without writing 2 lines?  Maybe I want to do more than 2 things to an element on click..

```
<p id="p">What color is an egg?</p>
    <button id="b">click for answer</button>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("p").innerHTML= "white";});
    document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("p").style.color="white";});
    </script>
```

Comment: typo -- getElementById

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){
     document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "white";
     document.getElementById("p").style.color = "white";
});
```

or better...

```
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){
     var el = document.getElementById("p");
     el.innerHTML = "white";
     el.style.color = "white";
});
```

Comment: yeah, that makes sense.. should have thought of that

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work?

```
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function()
{document.getElementById("p").innerHTML= "white";
document.getElementById("p").style.color="white";});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
var events = [];
events.push(function(){document.getElementById("p").innerHTML= "white";});
events.push(function(){document.getElementById("p").style.color="white";});
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) events[i]();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the general case you can use an anonymous function

```
(function (node) {
   // code operating on node = document.getElementById("b")
   node.addEventListener("click", function(){
     (function (node_in) {
        // code operating on node_in = document.getElementById("p")
        node_in.innerHTML = "white";
        node_in.style.color = "white";
     })(document.getElementById("p"));
   });
})(document.getElementById("b"));
```